# JSON won't parse to TableView in swift 3

Tags: json, uitableview, swift3

I am new with SwiftyJSON and ham building new app.
However, when I am trying to parse the data from the JSON, its appearing only in the console and in side the function only?

Is there anything wrong with my code ?

```
func CallNames(URl_read : NSMutableURLRequest)  {
    let Task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URl_read as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data,response,error) in
        if error != nil {                
            print(error)
        }
            let readJson = JSON(data: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers, error: nil)

           // let arrayNames =  readJson["Result"].arrayValue.map({$0["Names"].stringValue})
            if let stations = readJson["Result"].array {
                for d in stations {
                    let NamesInside = d.dictionaryValue["Names"]
                    if NamesInside != nil {
                        self.NamesResturant_.append((NamesInside?.string!)!)
                    }
               }                    
        }
     self.tableView.reloadData()
  })        
  Task.resume()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Names", for: indexPath) as! Rest_Cell

    // Configure the cell...
    if NamesResturant_.count != 0 {
        cell.RestName.text = NamesResturant_[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code is working fine but i was forget to change  the section of the table to 1 instead of 0